# jQuery clone method moves nested input element outside of parent

Tags: jquery, clone

I am trying to use the jQuery clone method to duplicate an input element as many times as needed. The input element is nested within a fieldset tag and other div tags.
The problem is that the cloned group of elements come out in a different order. More importantly the INPUT element is no longer nested where it was and this breaks the UI.

e.g. Original structure (simplified)

```
<fieldset><div><input /></div></fieldset>
```

The cloned outcome:

```
<fieldset><div></div></fieldset><input />
```

Here is a JSfiddle link showing the issue in action: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fxZ4/)

Comment: it is because of the use of selectors, since you are using `.find()` and `andSelf()` the matched element set which is used in `insertBefore()` is different from what was returned by the `clone()` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VRRuf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is stemming from the fact you are using incremental `id` attributes, and are trying to calculate the next in the sequence on the fly. This is *always* problematic, and is rarely the best solution.

Use `class` attributes to group similar elements - it's what they were designed for. Your code becomes much simpler too.

```
<div id="insert-placeholder"></div>
<fieldset class="template-image-upload-wrapper">
    <legend>Image upload</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input class='template_image_upload' class='form-control input-md' title='Upload an image.' name='editPage' type='file' value='' /> 
            <span class="help-block"></span>    
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

```js
$(".template-image-upload-wrapper").clone(false).insertBefore("#insert-placeholder");
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7fxZ4/1/)

Comment: *Or* just make the attribute changes after inserting the element: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/7fxZ4/2/

Comment: @oGeez I'm not saying it's impossible to achieve what the OP is trying, I'm just advising against it as it leads to more headaches. Using classes is much simpler and better semantically too.

Comment: No I agree, which is why I didn't post my comment as an answer. Your up-vote is from me.

Comment: @oGeez - Thanks! that was quick and has certainly sorted out the UI issue, but now with no unique identifiers how do I reference the different cloned elements?

Comment: @Wairowe Huh? This is Rory's answer. There are ways in which to target specific elements within a class, though: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/7fxZ4/3/

Comment: Ops! sorry I meant Rory. I came up with this: mClone = $(".template-image-upload-wrapper").clone(false).insertBefore("#insert-placeholder");
mClone.find("input").attr('id', 'image-upload-'+idx);

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for the answer! I especially like how you have simplified my code.